# How can I use ng-repeat and a previously-declared function within the template of an AngularJS directive?

Tags: javascript, templates, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Using AngularJS I'm attempting to create a directive to templatize questions in a form.  For a particular type of question, I want to create radio buttons for each number within a certain range.  I have an external function that returns an array of numbers given a lower and upper bound.

How can I use this external function, together with ng-repeat, to templatize this type of question?  Here's the code I've tried so far...

HTML:

```
<qtnrange qtn-variable="cxnTestVarA" first-num="1" last-num="5">
This is a test question. Pick a number between 1 and 5.</qtnrange>
<hr>
You picked {{cxnTestVarA}}.
```

JS:

```
var module = angular.module('app', [])
.directive('qtnrange', function() {
return {
    scope: {
        qtnVariable: '=',
        firstNum: '=',
        lastNum: '=',
        bounds: '&range',
    },
    template:
        '<div class=question>' + 
            '<label ng-transclude></label>' +
            '<label class="radio inline" ng-repeat="iter in bounds(firstNum, lastNum)"><input type="radio" value="{{iter}}" ng-model="qtnVariable">{{iter}} </label>' +
        '<hr></div>',
    restrict: 'E', // must be an HTML element
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
};
});

var range = function(start, end, step) {
    ... function that returns an array []
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle that demostrates the issue?

Comment: Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daEmw/1/)

Comment: Still not quite sure what it is you want to do here, but I've updated the jsFiddle to a working state here: http://jsfiddle.net/daEmw/3/

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what I wanted to do (have radio buttons for each number within a certain range) -- thanks for fixing my code!  If you put your response in as an answer to the question, I'll put it in as the correct response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example of your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/daEmw/3/

What I did was moving the range function onto the scope, and to use ng-click on the radio inputs instead of binding them with ng-model.

Basically, changing this:

```
module.directive('qtnrange', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            qtnVariable: '=',
            firstNum: '=',
            lastNum: '=',
            bounds: '&range',
        },
        template:
            '<div class=question>' + 
                '<label ng-transclude></label>' +
                '<label class="radio inline" ng-repeat="iter in bounds(firstNum, lastNum)"><input type="radio" value="{{iter}}" ng-model="qtnVariable">{{iter}} </label>' +
            '<hr></div>',
        restrict: 'E', // must be an HTML element
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
    };
});

var range = function() {

}
```

into this:

```
module.directive('qtnrange', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            qtnVariable: '=',
            firstNum: '=',
            lastNum: '='
        },
        template:
            '<div class=question>' + 
                '<label ng-transclude></label>' +
                '<label class="radio inline" ng-repeat="iter in range(firstNum, lastNum)"><input type="radio" value="{{iter}}" ng-click="setNum(item)">{{iter}} </label>' +
            '<hr></div>',
        restrict: 'E', // must be an HTML element
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.setNum = function(num) {
                $scope.qtnVariable = num;
            }
            $scope.range = function() {
                // ...
            }
        }
    };
});
```